# Azure Release Pipelines - Require Specific Number of Approvals

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My team wants to gate our release pipeline PROD stage on 2 approvals (exactly 2). It's clearly possible to gate on "any 1 approval" or "all approvals" in any order, but is it possible to require exactly 2?

I tried looking into Environments based on some ms doc I found, but I couldn't figure out how it was suppose to link to our release pipeline. The closest workaround I can think of is either a post-approval from the stage before and a pre-approval for the stage in question with the "user cannot approve if approved previous stage" checked (if that works the way I think it does), or look into manual intervention tasks (which seems hacky, though I haven't looked much into them).

Any advice or words of wisdom would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, all users must approve the deployment (in any order). If a
>   group is added, one user in the group must approve the deployment.

According to the definition of Approvers, if you want to achieve exactly two, you can only specify two users as approvers.

In addition, there should be no "user cannot approve if approved previous stage" option in Approval policies,the correct description is to "skip", not "cannot":

[image]

Comment: "According to the definition of Approvers, if you want to achieve exactly two, you can only specify two users as approvers."

That's what I was afraid of... thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks for clarifying the skip vs cannot, I totally understood it as "skip/ignore this user's vote"! :P